# Why can't I change the active Excel worksheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Function that is attempting to change the current active sheet ("Sheet1") to (Sheet2) and then assign a value to a cell in Sheet2.
However the ActiveSheet.name doesn't change and the assignment fails. see the code snippet.  The function is called from sheet1.

```
Dim oldwksheet as String

    oldwksheet = ActiveSheet.Name       'value is Sheet1     
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate     
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select      
    oldwksheet = ActiveSheet.Name       'value still is Sheet1"          
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F2") = Now() 'this fails.

end function
```

Why? What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Functions (UDF's) are invoked by Excel's calculation engine. They are not allowed to do certain things, like modifying application state, activating sheets.. and modifying other cells. Functions take input, compute a value, and return that value. Nothing more, nothing less. Who/what is calling this function?

Comment: Why on earth you need to activate sheet (no matter - UDF or just sub/function)?

Comment: Mathieu  I was calling the function from a cell in sheet1 using =ChangeActiveSheet,  You are correct and I now understand that a function will not work.  I used a sub and it worked no problem,  I am going to restructure my workbook to use a sub.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a **sub** and not a **function**.

A function can only return a value to the cell in which it resides.  It can't select or activate worksheets or deposit values in arbitrary cells.

Comment: Thank you -- I used a Sub and it worked no problem.  I learned something today.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't say why, but you could use a Function

assuming your function's named after "MyFunction" then place in relevant worksheet code pane the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count = 1 Then If Left(Target.Formula, 12) = "=MyFunction(" Then Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F2") = Now() 
End Sub
```

this way, whenever you type `=MyFunction()` in any cell of the relevant worksheet, the current date and time is being placed in cell F2 of Sheet2